# Load HTML fragments into Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I’m trying to develop an Electron application that supports a basic plugin architecture. The `main.js` process loads a basically empty 'Welcome' page, except for some kind of header section for title and which contains a drop-down menu listing the available plugins.

Each plugin has its own `renderer.js` file, configuration data etc. It also provides the necessary HTML to display inside the `div#plugin-container`. I’m hoping to have the renderer process load the HTML fragment into the existing web page inside the aforementioned `div`.

I understand that the `win.loadURL()` is for the `main.js` only and it loads an HTML to fill in the whole window. I’m looking to load a fragment into an existing page. jQuery has the `$('div#plugin-container').load()` method that would do what I need, but it’s loading HTML from a server only, as far as I can see. And I want to load it from within the Electron application.

Any ideas?

Disclosure: I posted this message previously on the Atom discussion board [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/load-html-fragments-into-electron/53454), but hope to get a better response from the SO community.

Comment: are you open to frameworks like [react](https://reactjs.org/)?

Comment: @Rhayene funny you should ask that question, I had a paragraph in my initial question saying that I'd like to avoid react and similar frameworks as to not add to the stuff I have to learn. I may get there in the end though. :-)

Comment: hey, how do you dynamically execute plugins' renderer.js scripts?

Comment: @VIPPER have a look here, not sure if it answers your question: https://github.com/jfix/pac-toolkit - I haven't looked at this code for a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever way you access the HTML you can always render it in your page if you parse it as a string. If you want to read from a file you can do something like:

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('path/to/thehtml.html', (err, data) => {
   document.getElementById('some-element').innerHTML = data
})
```

If you want the user to select the file you should use Electron's `dialog` API which allows you to prompt the user with a dialog for choosing a file. Or you could have an input where they can enter the text and read from there.

Comment: Thanks @limoragni, I'll try that tonight.

Comment: Yes! It works! I had to add `error` as the first parameter to the anonymous function call (`(error, data) => { ... }`) but it does work now! Thank you!

Comment: Oh yes, I missed the `err` arg. Thanks for pointing that out. I edited my answer.